# how to dynamically populate choices field from another model containing the values to be used - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, choicefield

I have a model that has some choices that the admin chooses while entering some data in the admin pannel. I am using the general way of making a choice field as below

```py
CATEGORY= (
    ('arbitration', 'arbitration'),
    ('binding precedent', 'binding precedent'),
    ('contempt', 'contempt'),
    ('execution of decree', 'executuon of decree'),
    ('limitations', 'limitations'),
    ('negative equality', 'negative equality'),
    ('od/ss/rd', 'Obitor Dicta / Sub Silenso-Ratio/ Decidendi'),
    ('review', 'review'),
    ('special relief', 'special relief'),   
)
  
)

class Civil(models.Model):
    law_category= models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=CATEGORY ,null=True, help_text="required")
```

Here the choices are hard coded. Now I want the admin to have control over what choices he can have inside **CATEGORY**. So what I thought would work is to create another model where he can enter the the values for **CATEGORY** and that would in return create some dynamic choices for the field `law_category= models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=CATEGORY ,null=True, help_text="required")`

The way I approached the problem was as below

```py
class CivilChoices(models.Model):
      key=models.CharField()
      value = models.CharField()
```

Here I thought of entering the key and values. But now I do not know how to get these values inside the **Civil** model for **CATEGORY** to use, or even if it is the right way to do it.

Please suggest me a way to create dynamic choices for the **law_category** field that get its choices from another model

Answer (score 0):

Use ForeignKey :

```
class Civil(models.Model):
    law_category = models.ForeignKey(CivilChoices, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Comment: but this is will not five a select field right. I want the select field but just add keys and values there from another model and not hardcode it.

Comment: also cannot apply this to a Multiselect field

Comment: For multiselect use many to many field. So if data is in database how is it hardcoded?

Comment: I'll try and get back to you